# Android http Post Login

Tags: php, android, http, authentication

I'm trying to make a login to my website via an Android app.
For some reason something always goes wrong.

Here's my site login structure:

- `Login.php` - the login form (username
  & password)
- `Auth.php` - login authentication page
  (gets the username & password from
  page - login.php (POST method))

I already have to interface with Username & Password (EditText both)

What is the method to make a login via android app?

here's my current login method

```
private void login() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("my auth.php file url");

    try {
        // Add user name and password
        String username = this.usernameField.getText();
        String password = this.passwordField.getText();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors or something?

Comment: That depends on how your back-end works. You need to know what parameters it accepts.

Comment: Actually it doesn't even get to   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: Please do post what errors you are seeing.

Comment: I don't get any errors, I created a TextView to handle the process status and I don't get any errors
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         statusText.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
         statusText.setText(e.toString());
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days ago I had some similar problems. 
 You can have a look at the following code.

```
public class API {
// constants
private final String TAG = "API";
private final String API_URL_SECURE = "your url";
private final String API_URL = "your url";
private static API instance;    

// data
private HttpClient client;  
private ClientConnectionManager cm;
private HttpPost post;    
private HttpContext httpContext;
private HttpParams params;

private API() {

    params      = new BasicHttpParams();
    httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 300);
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);                          
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register( new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80) );

    cm          = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
    client      = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);                        

}


public static API getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new API();
        return instance;
    }
    else
        return instance;
}

private static String getCredentials(String userName, String password){     
    return Base64.encodeBytes((userName + ":" + password).getBytes());
}

private String makeRequest(String url, JSONObject json, String userName, String userPassword) {

    try {          
        post            = new HttpPost(url);                                           
        StringEntity en = new StringEntity(json.toString());    

        post.setEntity(en);
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        if(userName != null && userPassword != null)
            post.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ getCredentials(userName, userPassword));           

        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post, httpContext);  
        HttpEntity   resEntity    = responsePOST.getEntity();

        return EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public synchronized String login(String user_name, String user_password){
    JSONObject json     = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject params   = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("method", "log_in_user");
        params.put("user_name", user_name);
        params.put("user_pass", user_password);
        json.put("params", params);
        String result = makeRequest(API_URL_SECURE, json, user_name, user_password);
        return result;          
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is that you are doing:

```
String username = this.usernameField.getText();
String password = this.passwordField.getText();
```

Assuming that usernameField and passwordField are EditText widgets, you should be doing:

```
String username = this.usernameField.getText().toString();
String password = this.passwordField.getText().toString();
```